# Command to copy one row to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Sub MoveRowtoAnotherTab()
'Created by Ruchita Rane

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim A As Long
    Dim B As Long
    Dim C As Long

    A = Worksheets("Contact").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    B = Worksheets("Lead Created").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    If B = 1 Then
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Lead Created").UsedRange) = 0 Then B = 0
    End If

    Set xRg = Worksheets("Contact").Range("C1:C" & A)

    On Error Resume Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     For C = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(A).Value) = "1" Then
            xRg(C).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Lead Created").Range("A" & B + 1)

                B = B + 1
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

My variable is K=1 to move the row from one sheet to another and I do not want to erase data in Contact. I am not good in VBA, Can someone please help?

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is. This code will not erase data. Where do you want to use K?

Answer (score 1):

I think you needed to change `A` to `C` in line `If CStr(xRg(A).Value) = "1" Then`

```
Option Explicit
Sub MoveRowtoAnotherTab()
'Created by Ruchita Rane

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim A As Long
    Dim B As Long
    Dim C As Long

    A = Worksheets("Contact").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    B = Worksheets("Lead Created").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    If B = 1 Then
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Lead Created").UsedRange) = 0 Then B = 0
    End If

    Set xRg = Worksheets("Contact").Range("C1:C" & A)

    'On Error Resume Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     For C = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(C).Value) = "1" Then
            xRg(C).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Lead Created").Range("A" & B + 1)

                B = B + 1
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```